# 8 Character Random Code

Tags: java, python, database, algorithm, unique

I've been through answers to a few similar questions asked on SO, but could not find what I was looking for.

Is there a more efficient way to generate 8 character unique IDs, base 36 (0-9A-Z), than generating a unique ID and querying the DB to see if it already exists and repeating until you get a unique ID that has not been used?

Other solutions I found use time, but this is perhaps too easy to guess and may not work well in distributed systems.  Consider these IDs to be promo codes.

Comment: Just wondering... Why would you need to do this in real life?  If you're looking for a unique key to serve as a primary key, why not use an Identity column or a guid?

Comment: guid would be too long.  this has to be something i can give to customers.  i think they would be overwhelmed with a promo code larger than 8-10 characters.

Comment: If I were you I'd look up the probability of generating a duplicate combined with the hashtable lookupt time to ensure it's not a dup--I think you will find very little potential benefit from this exercise.

Comment: serial number doesn't suffice? It will take almost no space at all to store existing IDs since you know they can't possibly collide, by the design of natural number.

Comment: @Lie: promo codes shouldn't be sequential, because you don't want somebody who has a promo code to be able to guess other peoples' codes.

Comment: the answer is YES you of course simply have to generate them randomly, and then, check that you have not used that one already. This is exactly how your bank account number, and the like, is created.  Note that **of course, obviously** you have to lock up the relevant table (or whatever you're working with) while you create one and check that it's unique.

Comment: Note that the overwhelming issue on this question is, Human-Readable-Ids simply have nothing to do with randomness.  they will be entirely decided by the marketing department. You would almost certainly not have zeros at the start. Many companies don't like zeros at the end. Personally I think never have three in a row, and most large commercial systems enforce that for IDs. If you are using letters ("your code is XMJUYTD") you will almost certainly simply leave out problem letters (I, O, etc). If you are mixing letters and numbers, you would probably leave out number zero. Etc etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I question that your "inefficient" approach is actually inefficient.  Consider this:

- There are 36^8 == 2,821,109,907,456 (2.8 Trillion) possible IDs.
- If you have N existing IDs, the chance of a new randomly generated ID colliding is N in ~2.8 trillion.
- Unless N is in the hundreds of billions, you "generate a unique ID and querying the DB to see if it already exists" algorithm will almost always terminate in one cycle.

With careful design, you should be able to generate a guaranteed unique ID in one database request, almost all of the time ... unless you have an awfully large number of existing IDs.  (And if you do, just add another couple of characters to the ID and the problem goes away again.)

If you want to, you can reduce the average number of database operations to less than one per ID by generating the IDs in batches, but their are potential complications, especially if you need to record the number of IDs that are actually in use.

But, if you have at most 150,000 IDs (I assume, generated over a long period of time) then creating the IDs in batches is not worth the effort ... unless you are doing a bulk upload operation.

Comment: Note that even if you do "pre-generate them". (Presumably because - say - you are concerned that you may be getting as many as one new users every minute, and that could - say - overheat your server room.)  You would, of course, *still just lock-and-check if it is really unique*  as a sanity check, since it's a completely expenseless operation.  The whole discussion is a bit bizarre.

Answer (score 10):

One option is to do it the other way round: generate a huge number of them in the database whenever you need to, then either fetch a single one from the DB when you need one, or reserve a whole bunch of them for your particular process (i.e. mark them as "potentially used" in the database) and then dole them out from memory.

Comment: Just to make sure I understood you correctly, I'd be doing the same thing as I described above, but just at an earlier, non-critical time?

Comment: This is a sensible approach. Do use a column called "in use" or something similar, and mark appropriately.

Comment: @Bradford: I suspect that if your ID space is sparsely populated, then the probability of a collision when you generate a number is very low, so you can do it at a critical time as long as it's not super-critical. If the ID space isn't sparsely populated, then you have another problem - you're within an order of magnitude of running out of IDs (and your database is occupying several TB).

Comment: @Steve.  Good point.  I'm expecting to generate 150,000 of these at most.

Comment: @Bradford: You should add that you "only" expect to generate that many in your question -- it's a very critical piece of information.

Comment: @Bradford: Yes, and in large batches. If you generate 20,000 of them, and ask the database to insert whichever ones are new (dropping the rest), that's likely to be more efficient than doing it one at a time.

Comment: Jon, thanks a lot.  martineau is right.  I should I have specified that I need only 150,000 of these.  In which case, I think this may be unnecessary.  I needed more, I think this would have been the best solution and thus answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, 8 base 36 digits is a bit small. It's only 2 million million possible IDs, so if you generate 1.4 million randomly you have about a half chance of a collision.

You could possibly use a PRNG with a large period, and map its current state to your ID space via some bijection. A 41 bit LFSR wouldn't be uncrackable, but might be reasonably OK if the thing you're protecting isn't all that valuable. You could distribute somewhat without having to access the DB all the time, by providing different nodes with a different position to start the cycle.

The trouble with any such deterministic method, of course, is that once it's broken it's completely broken, and you can no longer trust any IDs. So doling numbers out of a database is probably the way to go, and distribute by doling them out in batches of a thousand or whatever.

If you had a larger ID space, then you could use more secure techniques, for example the ID could consist of something to identify the source, an incrementing serial number for that source, and an HMAC using a key unique to the source.

Comment: If you're generating them randomly and not worrying about duplicates you have a MUCH higher chance of collisions that 50%, more like 99.99%. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer: I was trying to use the rule of thumb for Birthday collisions, that 50% probability of collision is achieved when the number of random samples is approximately the square root of the size of the space. Hence in this case 36^4, which is actually 1.67 million, because I misread my calculator and the size of the space is 2.8 million million, not 2 million million.

Comment: **facepalm** you're completely right. My brain glossed over the million million part. I'll leave the comment so others don't make the same mistake if that's alright. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If there is only one source of IDs (that is: you don't need to coordinate multiple independent sources on different machines) you can do the following:

- Calculate the maximum number of bits that a number may have so that it doesn't exceed the information contained in an 8-symbol string of 0-9A-Z. This would be `floor(log2(36^8))` = 41 bits.
- Have a counter (with 41 bits) start at zero
- Return `transform(counter++)` for each ID request

The `transform` function has to be bijective and can be an arbitrarily long sequence of the following operations (which are all bijective themselves when they are calculated modulo `2^41`):

- xor with a fixed value
- rotate left or right by a fixed value
- reorder the bits by a fixed mapping (a generalization of the rotation above)
- add or subtract a fixed value

When you are finished with that, you only need another function `encode(number)` to transform the number to base36.

Comment: i wouldn't do this ever, as soon as someone finds out the transform they can just "eat" other people's promo-codes by counting up and doing the same transform. to make it short: there's absolutely no randomness in your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some python code for generating random, base36 IDs.

```
import random

def base36encode(number, alphabet='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'):
    '''
    Convert positive integer to a base36 string.

    Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36#Python_Conversion_Code
    '''
    if not isinstance(number, (int, long)):
        raise TypeError('number must be an integer')

    # Special case for zero
    if number == 0:
        return '0'

    base36 = ''

    sign   = ""
    if number < 0:
        sign  ='-'
        number=-number

    while number != 0:
        number, i = divmod(number, len(alphabet))
        base36 = alphabet[i] + base36

    return sign + base36

def generateID(length=8):
    '''Generates a base36 ID.'''

    random.seed()
    id = base36encode(random.randint(0, (36**length)-1))

    # append 0s to ensure desired length
    while len(id) < length:
        id = '0' + id

    return id

def generateMultipleIDs(n):
    '''Generate n number of unique, base36 IDs.'''

    output = set()

    while len(output) < n:
        output.add(generateID())

    return output
```

Comment: I agree with Jon Skeet's idea.  So, you can use this code help populate your database.

Comment: This is the (relatively) easy part. The more challenging part is generating an ID that is not already in use -- which implies somehow remembering all those already generated and avoiding them.

Comment: True. You could use Python's pickle module to serialize a set of IDs. You could then load this set, generate another set, and ignore all IDs that intersect.

Comment: Your code also dodges the requirement about the ID having to be 8 base36 digits long. As for using a `set` to store which are used. Could be better to just save them in a plain text file and generate the `set` of them on the fly rather than using `pickle`.

Comment: My code doesn't dodge the 8 character requirement. It simply allows a programmer to easily upgrade to longer IDs if needed. As for saving / transferring generated IDs, a text file is a very neutral format. That could be less troublesome down the road, especially when using different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I once solved a similar problem using C++ involving a smaller number of possible IDs, but there might be useful to consider some ways to scale it up. Basically I created a big bitmap for all the possible IDs and would just lookup whether one was in use by testing the proper bit for it.

To minimize RAM requirements, I stored the bitmap in a raw binary file and used random-access file i/o to seek to the byte with the corresponding bit in it I needed to check and/or set.

Your much larger ID space would require a 328 GB bitmap, which is likely out of the question. On the other hand, a Python `set` of the used IDs might be acceptable, depending on how many IDs you think might actually end up being used. Other alternatives might be some sort of [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file) or sparse matrix technique, such as those in [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar to generate activation codes: 8-letter lowercase strings that are single-use. They are intended to be used within a short time of being generated (usually within minutes, but possibly not for up to a week), but must be unique. When they have been used, they are removed from the database.

I just generate a value and see if it is in use in the database. This works for now, because there are not heaps of unused codes sitting in the database, but are still not easy to guess, even if you have been provided with one.

As for the generation code:

```
def _generate_code(self, length):
    random.seed()
    candidates = string.lowercase[:26]
    result = ""
    for i in range(length):
        result += random.choice(candidates)
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it need to be cryptographically secure?

If not, pc(n) = a + bn, where b is prime relative to 36^8 will do. Use an array of byte.

```
foo(int n, byte[] a, byte[] b) {
  byte[] r = new byte[8];
  int carry=0;
  for(int i = 0; i<8;i++) {
    int x = carry + a[i] + n*b[i];
    r[i] = x % 36;
    carry = x / 36;      
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that in the circumstances (promo-codes) the ids need to be unpredictable ... not just "random looking"